# Replace ALU With Lookup Table?

Tags: alu, mips, architecture

*Disclaimer: So this is obviously a silly question and I want to start by saying I don't want to discuss the financial costs of this, as I'm aware CPU cache is expensive. As this hasn't been made obvious enough, this is PURELY ACADEMIC - NOT FOR IMPLEMENTATION. Think "thought experiment"*

I've been wondering if it would be possible to precompute all the work an ALU would do and store the results in a lookup table.

For this specific example, I've been looking at a subset of instructions the ALU is responsible for in a MIPS Architecture which is "AND, OR, add, sub, slt, NOR".

In this architecture, these operations would take 4 bits to encode which we'll call the control, as there are only 6 operations. In addition, we'd have to take two 32 bit values as input and return a 32 bit value as output along with 3 1 bit flags. (Details listed [here](http://personal.denison.edu/~bressoud/cs281-s08/homework/MIPSALU.html))

At a really high level, we'd use the 4 bit control, along with the two 32 bit inputs to return the 32 bit result and the 3 1 bit flags. So couldn't each control act as an offset to our cache, and use the input values to index into our lookup? We could even squeeze out some more memory for operations that have the commutative property (1+2 = 2+1)

I'm aware this is goofy question but I was curious if anyone had any insight. Perhaps it could be faster? If not, maybe use less electricity or generate less heat? At the very least it's interesting.

Comment: If it's so simple, why not implement it, on a FPGA or simulator, say, and do a performance test.

Comment: Can you do this in Matlab?

Comment: Are you talking about a lookup table with a 68 bit address (32 + 32 + 4)?

Comment: It would make sense for a nybble wide ALU, but 32 wide is a lot of address lines.

Comment: @MyOtherHead It was simply a thought experiment.

Comment: @Justin You'd use the input (32 + 32 + 4) to return (32 + 3) bits

Comment: @Neil_UK I understand it will take alot of storage, I was more interesting in potential speed, heat and power.

Comment: One example is the performance gap between FPGA and ASIC.

Comment: Like Neil says, it's a reasonably common technique when dealing with 4 or 8 bit wide inputs. At 32 bits it becomes infeasible, as shown in the existing answers.

Comment: @ThePhoton Your and Neil's comments are what I would like to accept. As it basically says, yes it would be better, but at this magnitude its infeasible. The "Yes it would be better" being the key

Comment: But it wouldn't be better. You're trading off time complexity for space complexity, and you can't just wish away one of them to make your chosen solution "better".

Comment: @ThePhoton Pardon, by better I meant more relevant, as no one has yet mentioned its a common technique. I'm aware of tradeoffs like time vs space. This whole question was essentially, exploring how much time complexity could we shift to space.

Comment: For certain functions you can gain a bit by having a lookup table + some computation, although that's more for things like log and sin than mere arithmetic. Arithmetic is *fast* on modern CPUs, the ALUs spend a majority of time idle.

Comment: Replacing the ALU with a lookup table for cost saving has actually been done in the past. Instead of addition and multiplication circuitry the IBM 1620 computer (from 1959) used a table in core memory to add or multiply two BCD digits. This earned it the nickname CADET (Can't Add, Doesn't Even Try). The IBM 1620 Model II upgraded to ALU hardware for addition/subtraction, but kept the multiplication table.

Answer (score 9):

A single 32-bit x 32-bit to 32-bit lookup table would require an untenable amount of space:

$$ 2^{32} \times 2^{32} \times 32 = 2^{69} \approx \mathrm{5.9\ quintillion\ bits} $$

This is flatly impossible to build. A single microchip can store perhaps 2<sup>40</sup> bits (~128 GB); you'd need *over 500 million* of these to store the full lookup table. (Halving the size by exploiting symmetries like `a+b=b+a` still leaves the size in the implausible range.)

If you want to consider the implications on heat/power and speed, though:

- If we generously assume that each of the 500+ million microchips draws 1 mA at 3.3V, you're looking at a total power consumption of roughly 1.8 MW. (Yes, that's *megawatts*.)
- If we assume that each of those chips is 2x2 cm and 0.5 cm thick (including the circuit board), and that they require no other support circuitry, the resulting device will be roughly a 10 meter cube. It takes light about 34 nanoseconds to cross 10 meters; even if we assume that it takes no time for one of these chips to look up a result, this would limit the speed of such a device to roughly 292 MHz.

Comment: I tried to cover this with the "I'm aware CPU cache is expensive". While I don't disagree with anything you wrote, can you add to your answer with your opinion on terms of speed, electrical usage and heat generation?

Comment: The fact that you'd need _over 500 million microchips_ should cover that. Work through the implications yourself. :)

Comment: @GregHilston Are you serious? 6 **Exabytes** is 6 *million Gigabytes*.

Comment: I'm not sure how else to phrase this, it was purely a question that I wasn't trying to translate into a physical solution. Purely theoretical and academic. I don't understand how I am not making that clear.

Comment: You are asking a purely "practical" questions about speed and electrical consumption. Which cannot be answered in terms of existing technology. Putting together such a large-scale system would require novel engineering solutions which will alter any possible answer to these.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I was hoping to talk about the current time it takes to perform such operations and perhaps speculate on how fast it could be looked up. The key here was a discussion and not a simple "This is not physically possible right now". I apparently posted this in the wrong community.

Comment: As you ask about heat and power, an ALU is a tiny fraction of a 'microchip', let's say 1/2000th, and you'd need 500 million full microchips to implement the lookup table. I make that around 10^12 more costly in heat, power, area, probably money, and likely no quicker on account of the speed of light for the address lines to traverse this assembly of chips.

Comment: My original question, that I did not post, was about the CPU but I figured asking about the ALU would be a simplified version.

Comment: @GregHilston Well, in this case the question would be off-topic, as it is neither a discussion forum nor a place to speculate.

Comment: If each chip stores 2^40 bits, you would only need 35 * 2^28 chips, or about 9.5 billion chips.  You could probably store at least 300 thousand chips per cubic meter.  You'd need 32 000 m^3 of room for just the ALU.  // I'd recommend buying several tonnes of uranium-235 for the power supply, or even better: a hydrogen fusion reactor.

Comment: @OskarSkog Not sure how you got that result; 2^32*2^32*32/2^40 = 2^29 ≈ 500M.

Comment: @duskwuff:  I read a comment made by OP three minutes after your answer.  "@Justin You'd use the input (32 + 32 + 4) to return (32 + 3) bits"

Comment: @OskarSkog Perhaps I should have asked 
"I have two operations (two bits) and two registers of two bits each (four bits total). Could precomputed be faster, less eletricity less heat." As I used MIPs as an example, assuming others would be familiar with it...

Comment: @GregHilston The choice of register width actually makes a huge difference here, as the size of the lookup table increases exponentially with the register size. It's actually a reasonable question for an 8-bit ALU.

Answer (score 5):

The bottom line is that a lookup table is made up of logic gates, and it always takes fewer gates to implement the kinds of ALU operations you're talking about *directly* rather than use a lookup table.

So, no matter how much technology advances, it never makes sense to use lookup tables over direct logic **using the same technology**.

FPGAs are a special case because of how they are used. In the first place, reconfigurability is their most important feature, and secondly, the tiny lookup tables that they use (typically 16×1 to 64×1) are very fast — faster than the interconnect logic and other details that contribute to their configurability.

Comment: I don't agree, a lookup table is mainly MEMORY and not logic gates

Comment: @ClaudioAviChami: How do you think that memory is implemented at the lowest level? It's basically gates -- lots of them! Even a mask ROM has a large decoder and OR gates to combine the data from different words.

Answer (score 0):

To add on the speed, to access the look up table it will take a clock cycle which would make execution fast but a lot of modern architectures like ARM and AVR execute instructions in a single cycle so the the trouble of all those required bits wouldn't gain you much. Additionally to create all the require bits, whether they are implemented as SRAM or DRAM you would ended having to use a pretty small technology node which would result in high leakage current and therefore high power consumption. Again if you were to implement your look up table in flash accessing flash is slow operation compared to what some CPU cores can run again negating the any speed gains

Comment: The limiting factor of speed is c, not the programming language, but 299792458 m/s.   I've guesstimated the volume of the ALU to a whopping 32 000 m^3.    A spherical ALU would have a radius of about 65 nanoseconds.    The rest of the digital stuff of the computer would fit in the center, but I've completely forgotten about the cooling system, power supplies, bypass capacitors and nuclear reactors.

Answer (score 0):

At 32-bit level, its not practical. But considerable excitement occurred in 1985, when 5-bit math was proposed for in-memory image processing.

By taking log(pixel_magnitude) and storing that, dynamic-range was good and actual edge-detection should occur.

We never built it. After all, who would want to perform 5-bit math in a memory?